# Appending print commands with .decode() method

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a script of about 300 lines (part of which is pasted below) with a lot of print commands. I am trying to cleanup the output it produces. If I leave it the way it is then all the print commands print bytes with \r\n on to the console.

I figured if I add .decode('utf-8') in front of the variable that I need to print then the output is what I should be expecting (uni-code string). For example, compare print (data1) and print (data3) commands below. What I want to do is to go through all of the code and append .decode() to every print statement.

All the print commands are in this format: Print (dataxxxx)

```
import telnetlib
import time
import sys
import random
from xlwt import Workbook

shelfIp = "10.10.10.10"
shelf = "33"

print ("Shelf IP is: " + str(shelfIp))
print ("Shelf number is: " + str(shelf))


def addCard():

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(shelfIp)

    ### Telnet session
    tn.read_until(b"<",5)
    cmd = "ACT-USER::ADMIN:ONE::ADMIN;"
    tn.write(bytes(cmd,encoding="UTF-8"))
    data1 = tn.read_until(b"ONE COMPLD", 5)
    print (data1.decode('utf-8'))

    ### Entering second network element
    cmd = "ENT-CARD::CARD" + shelf + "-" + shelf + ":TWO:xyz:;"
    tn.write(bytes(cmd,encoding="UTF-8"))
    data3 = tn.read_until(b"TWO COMPLD", 5)
    print (data3)

    ### Entering third network element
    cmd = "ENT-CARD::CARD-%s-%s:ADM:ABC:;" %(shelf,shelf)
    tn.write(bytes(cmd,encoding="UTF-8"))
    dataAmp = tn.read_until(b"ADM COMPLD", 5)
    print (dataAmp)

    tn.close()

addCard()
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: As a side note: I hope that the IP and other strings you provided in the sample code aren't real, or aren't in use. Security wise, you shouldn't paste sensitive information about your system or software. Instead, put dummy strings that don't have any meaning but just show what ever you need to show to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking into doing some sort of find-replace on the code, you can try this:

```
import re

f = open('script.py','rb')
script = f.read()
f.close()

newscript = re.sub("(print\(.*)\)", "\g<1>.decode('utf-8'))", script)

f = open('script.py', 'wb')
f.write(newscript)
f.close()
```

What I did in the regular expression:

1. Catch text that contains `print(......)` and save the `print(.....` part into group 1
2. Replace the text after the `print(....` which is `)` with: `.decode('utf-8'))` using the syntax `\g<1>` which takes the saved group number 1 and put that as the prefix in the replaced text.

Answer (score 0):

Appending `.decode()` to `print()` statements will fail because `.decode()` is a `string` method.

```
>>> x=u"testing"
>>> print(x).decode('utf-8')
testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

You must apply `.decode('utf-8')` to the variables you wish to decode, which is not easily accomplished using regex based tools.